# ORDER BY on timestamp field makes my query slow. How to optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I'm working on a MySQL database that stores "Facebook-like" images: every user follows a set of "artists", and these artists upload images.

I wrote a query that, for a given user, returns the images of all the artists he follows, that are more recent than 30 days, sorted by date:

```
SELECT img.id, img.url, a.name

FROM (SELECT artist FROM user_follow_artist WHERE user = <USER_ID>) AS f -- need to work only on the followed artists
JOIN artistimage AS img ON img.artist = f.artist -- join on the table that contains the images (8.000.000 rows!)
JOIN artist AS a ON a.id = img.artist -- join on artist table to add details on image's owner

-- following: where + orderby that slow down everything
WHERE img.uploadDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
ORDER BY img.uploadDate DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

The query tooks an average of 30 seconds, the more the user follows artists, the more it takes.
Here are some details:

- As written, the artistimage table is 8 millions rows big
- If I remove the ORDER BY clause, the time drops to 2-3 seconds
- img.uploadDate is a TIMESTAMP and it's INDEXED
- The engine is InnoDB

I hoped indexing uploadDate could increase the speed, but nothing changed. How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: Table structures

```
artist
------------------
id (integer, primary)
name (string)

user_follow_artist
------------------
user (integer, foreign key on user.id, indexed)
artist (integer, foreign key on artist.id, indexed)

artistimage
------------------
id (integer, primary)
artist (integer, foreign key on artist.id, indexed)
url (string)
uploadDate (timestamp, indexed)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id      select_type     table               type        possible_keys       key         key_len     ref             rows    Extra
1       PRIMARY         <derived2>          ALL         NULL                NULL        NULL        NULL            327     Using temporary; Using filesort
1       PRIMARY         img                 ref         artist,uploadDate   artist      9           img.artist      36      Using where
1       PRIMARY         user                eq_ref      PRIMARY             PRIMARY     8           db.img.artist   1    
2       DERIVED         user_follow_artist  ref         PRIMARY,user        user        8                           327     Using index
```

If I remove the ORDER BY, the EXPLAIN is the same but without `Using temporary; Using filesort` in first row.

Comment: You should avoid subqueries, and you don't need it at all here. And add the `explain select ..` output

Comment: It would also be useful to know exactly how these tables are indexed and whether there are any FK relationships between them. I do not think the sub-query is the problem here, since it selects the same data regardless of the order by and limit. Explain plan with and without the order by clause will definitely help.

Comment: Indexing the artist field in the tables joined using it could help.

Comment: I've updated the question with table structures. Explain is incoming...

Comment: Added explain, too

Answer (score 0):

I think your "Limit 50" is confusing you.  It's getting you the first 50 rows with no criteria, which will always return fast.
When you add the where and order by clauses, it will require MySQL to fetch all rows and then sort and filter to get your results.

I think if you took out the WHERE, ORDER **and** LIMIT 50, you will see your query takes a long time to fetch all rows.

To speed it up, you can try re-writing your query.
You can make a temp table for your "(SELECT artist FROM user_follow_artist WHERE user = )" set.

You can move the WHERE clause to the JOIN like this:

```
JOIN artistimage AS img ON img.artist = f.artist AND img.uploadDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: I followed your hints: moved WHERE clause and created the temporary table. The query seems a little bit faster but it still tooks like 15 seconds... Is it the best I can reach?

Comment: If I needed speed and had the time....I'd look into using a memory based MySQL instance.  Runs a lot faster than on Disk, but you will need to keep a Disk copy replicated of your DB.  Other thing to do is partition your 8 million row table...You would need to decide what partitions to use, and may need to re-write your queries to include the partition criteria so the query jumps to the correct partition

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for `user_follow_artist`, that table should be joined as is. Despite that, the problem is the query is not using the index in `uploadDate`. Try this:

```
SELECT
    img.id,
    img.url,
    a.name
FROM
    user_follow_artist AS f
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, url, uploadDate
        FROM artistimage
        WHERE uploadDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    ) img ON ( img.id = f.artist )
    INNER JOIN artist AS a ON ( a.id = img.id )
WHERE
    f.user = <USER_ID>
ORDER BY
    img.uploadDate DESC
```

If the subquery doesn't returns too many results, this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's simplify the query, since `IN ( SELECT ... )` does not optimize well:

```
SELECT  img.id, img.url, a.name
    FROM  user_follow_artist AS f
    JOIN  artistimage AS img  ON img.artist = f.artist
    JOIN  artist AS a  ON a.id = img.artist
    WHERE  img.uploadDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
      AND  f.user = <user_id>
    ORDER BY  img.uploadDate DESC
    LIMIT  50
```

Then let's get the best indexes.  But, alas, you are filtering on one table and ordering and limiting on another table.  So, let's add some *potentially* useful indexes and hope for the best:

To help the Optimizer if it starts with the `WHERE f.user...`:

```
f: INDEX(user, artist)
img: INDEX(artist, uploadDate)
```

To help the Optimizer if it starts with the `WHERE img.uploadDate... ORDER BY...`:

```
img: INDEX(uploadDate)
f: INDEX(artist, user)
```

Note that most of those are "composite" indexes, and the order of the columns is critical.

I would much prefer seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` than the prose you provided.

If `user_follow_artist` is a many:many mapping table, I strongly recommend following the tips in [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: Well... I simplified then I followed the `WHERE img.uploadDate... ORDER BY...` case, so I added the missing indexes but nothing changes.

Comment: "Nothing changes" -- as in still slow?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.